# How can I use standalone vue library in a vue application?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I am trying to use a vue component library, which is loaded by a script tag, within a vue application. That component library is using a webpack setup and uses the setting `externals` to exclude all vue dependencies. So the host bundle which is using that library has to ship vue and other needed dependencies.
The component library itself is using vue cli with the script `vue-cli-service build --target lib` to build a `lib.umd.js` file. Inside the `index.html` of my host bundle I am just including that file by a script tag. The webpack setup of the host bundle uses `config.externals(['@test/my-component-library'])` to exclude the component library which is being loaded externally. Inside the host bundle I am using the component library like this:

```
import { MyComponent } from '@test/my-component-library'
```

When I run my application, I get the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`. This error happens in the following line of my host bundle:

```
/*!*******************************************************!*\
  !*** external "@test/my-component-library" ***!
  \*******************************************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {
eval("module.exports = @test/my-component-library;//# sourceURL=[module]\n//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJmaWxlIjoiQHRlc3QvbXktY29tcG9uZW50LWxpYnJhcnkuanMiLCJzb3VyY2VzIjpbIndlYnBhY2s6Ly8vZXh0ZXJuYWwgXCJAdGVzdC9teS1jb21wb25lbnQtbGlicmFyeVwiPzFjOTAiXSwic291cmNlc0NvbnRlbnQiOlsibW9kdWxlLmV4cG9ydHMgPSBAdGVzdC9teS1jb21wb25lbnQtbGlicmFyeTsiXSwibWFwcGluZ3MiOiJBQUFBIiwic291cmNlUm9vdCI6IiJ9\n//# sourceURL=webpack-internal:///@test/my-component-library\n");
/***/ })
```

Does anyone know why webpack is producing such code and how I can correct it?

Comment: From https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/ I'm not sure you have to set the type of exported module such as root?

Comment: The error is gone if I use `config.externals({'@sldo/sldo-crm-kundenaktionen-plugin': {root: '@sldo/sldo-crm-kundenaktionen-plugin' } })`. But now I am getting `Cannot read property 'MyComponent' of undefined`. Its because of my import `import { MyComponent } from '@test/my-component-library'` does not work. What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found the solution. So first of all I had a wrong configuration for `externals`. The correct configuration is:

```
config.externals({
  '@test/my-component-library': {
    root: '@test/my-component-library',
    commonjs2: '@test/my-component-library',
    commonjs: '@test/my-component-library',
    amd: '@test/my-component-library',
  },
})
```

In the component library I had to add the webpack configuration `config.output.library('MyComponentLibrary')` so that the object `MyComponentLibrary` is globally available in window scope. Then I had to remove the import statement in the host bundle. To register the component I had to add this line to my vue file:

```
components: {
  'MyComponent': MyComponentLibrary.MyComponent,
}
```

But now I have another problem. The component library itself is using vuetify (which is another component library). But I have also added vuetify to the `externals` option because my host bundle already contains vuetify. And now I am getting lots of `Unknown custom element` exceptions. So apparently my component library does not find the vuetify components in my host bundle. Are there any solutions for this problem?

Comment: I think you will have a better change of getting an answere if you post a new question